# How to start a process in PM2 with custom command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command, pm2

I need to run this command in order for my python script to work.

```
$ xvfb-run python3 test.py
```

How can I achieve this with *PM2 start*?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution.

I created a [FILENAME].sh file with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/project
xvfb-run python3 test.py
```

And execute with PM2:

```
pm2 start [FILENAME].sh
```